# Lagrange method - non-linear system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have to compute optimal parametres of **truncated cone** so that its Volume is fixed (lets say it is 1) and its surface is minimal using Lagrange method

These are equations desribing my object:
\begin{equation}
 V(R, r, h) =  \frac{\pi}{3} h (R^2 + Rr + r^2) = 1
\end{equation}

My Cone doesnt have a top (its basically a cup)
\begin{equation}
 S(R, r,  h) = \pi(R + r) \sqrt{(R - r)^2 + h^2} + \pi r^2
\end{equation}

Lagrange equation:
\begin{equation*}
 L(R, r, h, \lambda) = \pi(R + r) \sqrt{(R - r)^2 + h^2} + \pi r^2 - \lambda(\frac{\pi}{3} h (R^2 + Rr + r^2) - 1)
\end{equation*}

I computed all the partial derivations, too (Im not sure if they are correct, so pardon any mistakes please):
\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial R} L(R, r, h, \lambda) = \frac{\pi(h^2 + 2R(R-r))}{\sqrt{h^2 + (R - r)^2}} - 2\lambda \frac{\pi}{3}hR - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}hr= 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial r} L(R, r, h, \lambda) = \frac{\pi(h^2 + 2r(r-R))}{\sqrt{h^2 + (R - r)^2}} - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}hR - 2\lambda \frac{\pi}{3}hr= 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial h} L(R, r, h, \lambda) = \frac{\pi h(r + R)}{\sqrt{h^2 + (R - r)^2}} - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}R^2 - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}Rr - \lambda \frac{\pi}{3}r^2= 0
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \lambda} L(R, r, h, \lambda) = - \frac{\pi}{3} h (R^2 + Rr + r^2) + 1 = 0
\end{equation*}

The problem is, that this leads to a non-linear system of equations and I cant seem to be ale to solve them. Do you know how to find a correct solution (and how) for my parametres **R, r, h?**

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I computed these equations using Math software.. I guess its too difficult do do it by myself:

$r = 0$, $R = \frac{(3/\pi)^{1/3}}{\sqrt{2}}$, $h = 2(\frac{3}{\pi})^{1/3}$, $\lambda = 4(\frac{\pi}{3})^{1/3} $